# How to get Issues with Assigned Company Names via PowerQuery Connector

Tags: powerquery, autodesk-construction-cloud

I'm using the PowerBI/PowerQuery Connector for AutodeskConstructionCloud and trying to build a list of Issues in a project with the assigned user or company. I can convert the 12 to 16 digit alphanumeric user_id to names via the admin_users endpoint. But I can't find any keys matching the assigned company ids with their 9 digit numeric assignee_id. All company related end points use much longer UUIDs that what is provided in the assignee_id field.